# Word File savings without closing are Not Uploaded to the server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

In my case, I want to build my own "drop box" like application which I am going to use as a part of my another project. 
Discription: 
When a word file is opened in the "drop box" folder(inside the folder where changes to the files, file creations deletions ect.. are identified). pictures, txts, txt updates are uploaded to the server without any issue.
But when it comes to office documents. office document creation is uploaded.

Problem:
when the word file is opened, and do some update and save it. the file can not be uploaded due to permission error. even the opened file can not be copied to another place and then uploaded. 
Any one faced this kind of issue, and any sugessions.
But we can manually copy and save a opened and saved(but not closed) to another location

But in the program it is not allowed.

Comment: Did you try opening file with advanced sharing option? by default files are opened with exclusive lock so you can't access them as they are in use.

Comment: Thanks, I anm working on it what you have said. I don't want to open any file. What I want is to upload what ever the changes happened to the file. saving word file is identified as a change but the access to that particular file is not allowed. I'll see is there any overrides in ftp upload method to set the sharing option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another copy of file, this is important because uploading may be slower and reading shared file may lead to conflicts for Word, so what you can do is, you can create a copy quickly on temp file and upload the temp file.

```
string tmp = Path.GetTempFileName();

using(Stream s = new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,
    // following option will let you open
    // opened file by other process
    FileShare.ReadWrite)){

   using(FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(tmp)){
      // this will copy file to tmp
      s.CopyTo(fs);
   }

}

// upload  tmp  file...
```

Comment: Cheers!!.. This worked and thanks a lot. I just had to drag and drop the code.:) I thought there should be a configuration or something to make my program to work with MS office apps which is more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is similar to what we faced. In our case we are all connected to a domain directory and the problem was the antivirus installed on our server gives read/write permissions to users (executing exe, installing apps). so you specifically need to give a user the right to execute an app that wants to use another app, in this case office docs.
The problem extended to asp apps using Crystal Reports. hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks leni, I'll see to my best. Thanks a lot,, I am really confused about this issue. Im not in a point were re thinking the design and everything

Comment: @leni, I dont think antivirus is an issue, because op is able to access file when it is not opened by word, Word locks file for exclusive access, only shared access is allowed.

Comment: I have tried on what you have done. What you have said was correct and I checked to see weather there are setting that can give my application permission to use MS office. But I was unable to find such. But I still do not know there is something. Thanks a lot for the guidance.